# Filesystems that handle data-duplication efficiently and transparently

Tags: linux, windows, mac, filesystems, duplicate

**Are there filesystems that handle data-duplication efficiently and transparently for the user?**

Example:

- I have `C:\documents\2019\bigfile.csv` (250 MB)
- I copy it to `C:\temp\bigfile.csv`, the used space on disk is still 250 MB (and not 500 MB!), [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) style
- I modify a few rows of `bigfile.csv` : the space used on disk is probably 251 MB (and still not 500 MB)

Example 2:

- I have a file `myOSinstalldisk.iso` somewhere on disk
- 6 months later, without noticing, I re-download the same file from internet, and save it somewhere else: **the OS *automatically* notices that and in fact no new space on disk is used**

This could work transparently if the OS automatically splits every file into chunks of, say, 1 MB, and save their SHA256 hash (for each I/O operation). In example 2, when saving `myOSinstalldisk.iso` to disk, the OS would notice the chunks are already in the FS (SHA256 hash already present in the hash table), and there's no need to waste disk space again for that.

**Which FS do support this on Windows? Are there some for Mac? Linux?**

See also: [Storing duplicate files efficiently on linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/568444/storing-duplicate-files-efficiently-on-linux)

PS: I'm not looking for Windows shortcuts, nor symbolic links, nor junctions, etc. (I already know and use this)

---

Such a FS would have for example:

```
Chunk table
==========
SHA256 of the chunk         Location on disk (sector)
2cb4b1431b84ec15...         3467634
d35ed83bb927e27e...         23789
8967d75f4bcd9cc4...         872372
b25c8d879ae23e18...         1265152
...

File table 
==========
File                        Chunks
/home/user/file_a           8967d75f4bcd9cc4... b25c8d879ae23e18... 2cb4b1431b84ec15...
/home/user/file_b           b25c8d879ae23e18... d35ed83bb927e27e...
```

In this (pseudo)-example, we see that `file_a` and `file_b` share a common chunk of 1MB.

Of course this is tricky for many reasons: let's say we have 2 duplicate files `file_a` and `file_b` and we just append 1 byte at the beginning of `file_b`, then the SHA256 hash of each chunk will be different and thus considered as different data... Also such a FS would need to keep a counter of the number of files which use a specific chunk, in order to know when it's no longer needed (garbage-collector-style), etc.

Comment: In Linux I use Btrfs and `alias cp='cp --reflink=auto'`. It's a tiny bit of what you want to achieve though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's close, that's right. Would it also detect automatically a duplicate that we have *not* created ourself with `cp`, i.e. example 2?

Comment: No, that's why I called it "a tiny bit". I have used `duperemove` *on demand*, so not automatically. More information [here maybe](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication).

Comment: Note: I had read that the newest FS on Mac OS can do deduplication, but it seems it's not fully supported: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8096756

Answer (score 5):

## ZFS

ZFS supports in-band block-based deduplication. It's a filesystem/LVM hybrid with good support on Linux and FreeBSD. ZFS provides a lot of awesomeness: basically everything, from file data to filesystem metadata, is checksummed, so filesystem corruption can be detected immediately and even healed using RAID-Z (RAID managed solely by ZFS itself).

There's a price to pay though. First, performance won't be as good as with traditional filesystems. ZFS is focused on reliability, not speed. Second, basic ZFS requires at least 1 GB of RAM + 1 GB of RAM for each 1 TB of storage you wish to deduplicate (information about available blocks must be stored somewhere for deduplication to be efficient). It's important that it must be ECC RAM (used in servers and Apple computers, regular PCs use non-ECC) because unlike with traditional filesystems flipped bits won't just damage data - if eg. a metadata checksum is corrupted, it can irrecoverably damage the filesystem. ECC fixes this by ensuring RAM errors will never make it to disk.

Comment: Thanks! So is deduplication fully automatic or do we have to run a `dedupe-now` command every now and then? In the scenario of my example 2, would ZFS notice *on-the-fly* that the newly-downloaded file uses chunks that we already have on disk? If so, what is the command to see that? and `size of a file` vs. `real size used on disk` (which would be less in case the data is duplicated) ?

Comment: PS: if you can add a few lines of demo code to create fs/mount/copy a file on the volume/copy it twice/notice the space miraculously saved, it would be awesome to understand the concept and for future reference! (in case you have time, and interested by the topic of course!)

Comment: Yes, that's in-band deduplication so it happens on the fly (as opposed to out-of-band deduplication supported for example by Btrfs). Your 2nd example works as expected. 1st example depends on kind of modification you perform: if you add or remove something or make an edit that has different count of removed and added bytes, blocks following edited one will be misaligned and deduplication won't be possible. "Real size used on disk" is a vague concept, both of these files actually take up disk space - it's just the same space. Unfortunately I can't provide a demo, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this additional information!